# How to write a sql query that returns matches from a two searchvalues

Tags: sql, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to create a **search-function** in which a user can combine *two values* to search for a person in a contacts list.
I want the database to return *posts* that have matches in both values.

Right now I have tried to do this:

`input = searchValueA, searchValueB`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ContactsList
WHERE lastName LIKE '%searchValueA%'
    OR firstName LIKE '%searchValueA%'
    OR company LIKE '%searchValueA%'
    OR phoneNumber LIKE '%searchValueA%'
        AND lastName LIKE '%searchValueB%'
   OR firstName LIKE '%searchValueB%'
   OR company LIKE '%searchValueB%'
   OR phoneNumber LIKE '%searchValueB%';
```

But this returns posts that match either of the searchvalues and both. I only want to get posts where both search values matches.
Can I redefine the query to make it do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want parentheses in that condition:

```
WHERE (lastName LIKE '%searchValueA%' OR
       firstName LIKE '%searchValueA%' OR 
       company LIKE '%searchValueA%' OR
       phoneNumber LIKE '%searchValueA%'
      ) AND
      (lastName LIKE '%searchValueB%' OR
       firstName LIKE '%searchValueB%' OR
       company LIKE '%searchValueB%' OR
       phoneNumber LIKE '%searchValueB%'
      );
```